# Validating jsonSchema against a Json String

Tags: json, jsonschema, jsonparser

I have a input Json that i would like to validate against a schema at the server side in a JAVA Rest API. I would like to call custom function in the schema. whats the standard to follow and are there any samples. Also in writing the schema is there a standard and does jackson provide any Schema parsers.

I have a sample schema provided to me i would like to call a custom function in peril property

```
    {
  "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {

  },
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "General": {
      "$id": "/properties/General",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "Name": {
          "$id": "/properties/General/properties/Name",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "The Name Schema ",
          "default": ""
        },
        "Peril": {
          "$id": "/properties/General/properties/Peril",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "The Peril Schema ",
          "default": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And i have the following json. I want to call a custom function on Peril value

```
    {
  "General": {
    "Name": "NAEQ_DCN_MAR21",    
    "Peril": "Earthquake"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON schema is using Draft 7 of the spec, which is not supported by Jackson as far as I know. To support Draft 7, you may use [Everit's JSON schema validator](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema). You can find JSON validating/parsing examples in the README. It uses [org.json API](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/), so this API's JSONObject class will allow you to access the Peril value.

Comment: The example i gave is for a simple json but i have multiple functions that i need to run and with different fields.. How do i achieve that.

Comment: Same thing. the API's JSONObject allows you to get anything in the JSON using one of the get*() methods: http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html